# javax/validation/Path GWT Java Maven converstion

Tags: gwt, maven-2, smartgwt

I am using GWT in my project., recently I tried converting a manual compilation of GWT + Java + tomcat to a maven project., almost I am able successfully package it to a war.,  BUt when I deployed on tomcat  I got followin error:

> EVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Path
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>           at                  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.SerializationPolicyLoader.loadFromStream(SerializationPolicyLoader.java:196)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.loadSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:90)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doGetSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:293)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.getSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:157)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:455)

Here is what i added for my added in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
 <version>${gwt.version}</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
 <version>${gwt.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

as dependencies.

Kindly help me.

What I need to add more to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) that is causing the problem. `compile` is actually the default scope so this could be omitted from the first dependency if you want.

The problem is in the second artifact which is declared as `provided`. This means that the application is expecting the web container to provide that library/classes. It looks like it is not providing the required classes, which results in the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Removing the `<scope>provided</scope>`, will instruct Maven to package that library with the application and Tomcat should be able to get past that error.

There are no compile-time errors since the `gwt-user` is available at compile time. It is simply not available at run-time for Tomcat.

Comment: yes Yes, That's great. This worked., Now I am able to launch my application. Thanks andy thanks alot.